# Read-only cell is editable

Tags: excel

I have weird problem when I am trying to lock cells to read only.

What I do:

1.) Select all, right click and switch to protection. Uncheck locked.

2.) Select cells which should be read only and set them to locked.

3.) In the end I set protection to worksheet.

[image]

It is right but what is strange it does not lock all what I have wanted. Let's say I locked A1, A2 and A3 by this way but only A1 and A2 is not editable (and is read only) but A3 is editable.

When I unprotected sheet and check if cell is locked ... yes it is.

Why it does this thing?

Comment: Please check:  `Review->Allow Users to Edit Ranges` option. You can define user rights to bypass protection there. If it doesn't help, a small sample demonstrating the issue could help investigate it.

Comment: Perfect, it was that problem. Thank you. If you will write answer I will accept it to give you some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check: Review->Allow Users to Edit Ranges option. You can define user rights to bypass protection there.